Update background style and Postgres table using onValueChange with Next.js and shadcn
I have the following code and I am trying to update the background color of my TableRow element while also updating "State" column in my "Devices" table in my Postgres serverless backend. I also want to make sure the Select option persists on the frontend, it is resetting to the SelectTrigger value ("Choose") when reloading the page.
I originally had it without the .bind() function and so the background color of the TableRow's were updating, but I wasn't touching the backend. Now that I've added the .bind() function it's only updating in the database, but not updating the TableRow's background color.
function DeviceRow({ device } : { device: SelectDevice }) {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState('')

    const updateBackground = updateState.bind((value: string) => {
        if (value == "In Use") {
            setStyle("bg-background")
        } else if (value == "Out of Service") {
            setStyle("bg-red-100")
        } else if (value == "Reassignment") {
            setStyle("bg-yellow-100")
        } else if (value == "Scrapped") {
            setStyle("bg-orange-100")
        } else if (value == "Consulting") {
            setStyle("bg-blue-100")
        }
    }, device.tag)

  return (
    <TableRow className={style}>
        <TableCell>
            <Select onValueChange={updateBackground}>
                <SelectTrigger className="w-[180px]">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Choose"/>
                </SelectTrigger>
                <SelectContent>
                    <SelectItem value="In Use">In Use</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="Out of Service">Out of Service</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="Reassignment">Reassignment</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="Scrapped">Scrapped</SelectItem>
                    <SelectItem value="Consulting">Consulting</SelectItem>
                </SelectContent>
            </Select>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell className="md:table-cell">{device.tag}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="md:table-cell">{device.name}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.email}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.devEmpID}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.model}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.specs}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.os}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.location}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">{device.initialStart}</TableCell>
        <TableCell className="hidden md:table-cell">
            <Dialog>
                <DialogTrigger>
                    <NotesIcon></NotesIcon>
                </DialogTrigger>
                <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px] lg:max-w-[550px]">
                    <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
                        <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center pt-5">
                            <Textarea className='col-span-4'></Textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <DialogFooter>
                        <Button type="submit">Save Changes</Button>
                    </DialogFooter>
                </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
        </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
}

I've tried creating a separate .bind() function inside of my updateBackground arrow function, but the "value" variable is not visible to the .bind(). I've also tried calling a separate function within my arrow function and then having .bind() inside of that function, but no luck.
